# Wrapping std::format in a template function fails to compile with the latest MSVC compiler update

Tags: c++, format, variadic-templates

I'm a bit stumped as to why this code has suddenly stopped compiling:
https://godbolt.org/z/hhM5GG78x

But if I change the compiler back v19.31, it will compile:
https://godbolt.org/z/11j8WbEzG

Here's the code in question:

```
#include <format>
#include <string>

template <typename... Args>
void FormatString(const std::string_view& fmt_str, Args&&... args)
{
    puts(std::format(fmt_str, args...).c_str());
}

int main()
{
    FormatString("This is a {}.\n", "test");
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the error message I'm receiving:

```
<source>(7): error C7595: 'std::_Basic_format_string<char,const char (&)[5]>::_Basic_format_string': call to immediate function is not a constant expression
<source>(7): note: failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime
<source>(7): note: see usage of 'fmt_str'
<source>(12): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void FormatString<const char(&)[5]>(const std::string_view &,const char (&)[5])' being compiled
```

It's complaining about fmt_str being used outside of it's lifetime.  I'm failing to see how this is the case?

Answer (score 8):

The first argument to `std::format` must be known at compile-time, since the format string is specified to be only constructible as a constant expression. The purpose is to guarantee compile-time errors for invalid format strings.

`fmt_str` is a function parameter and so its value is never a compile-time constant.

You can use [`std::vformat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/vformat) instead, but it will perform no compile-time checks of the format string, instead delaying it to runtime (throwing `std::format_error` on error):

```
puts(std::vformat(fmt_str, std::make_format_args(args...)).c_str());
```

If you don't need `fmt_str` to be runtime-time-dependent, you can pass it as a template paramter instead. Unfortunately this isn't quite so straight-forward at the moment since `std::string` and `std::string_view` cannot be used for that and string literals can't be passed directly via `const char*` non-type template argument.

So you would probably want to create your own structural fixed-length string type that can be used as non-type template parameter, e.g. here a very minimal version for the use case, which you would probably want to extend as suits your needs:

```
template<std::size_t N>
struct fixed_string {
    char str[N];
    constexpr fixed_string(const char (&str_)[N]) noexcept {
        std::ranges::copy(str_, str);
    }
};

template <fixed_string fmt_str, typename... Args>
void FormatString(Args&&... args)
{
    puts(std::format(fmt_str.str, args...).c_str());
}

int main()
{
    FormatString<"This is a {}.\n">("test");
    return 0;
}
```

I would assume that MSVC simply hadn't yet implemented the requirement that the first parameter of `std::format` be constructible as a constant expresssion in the previous versions.

The requirement was added after C++20 for C++23, but if understand correctly applies retroactively to C++20 as defect report as well, going by the votes listed in the paper [here](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2216r3.html) which contains the relevant changes.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I am okay with the argument string being known at compile time.  So I would like to avoid vformat if possible.  I decided to steal from how stl implements format with _Basic_format_string as the argument type.
https://godbolt.org/z/4hzqsEWf9   It compiles!  But might be inappropriate?

Comment: @LeoViolette That's not a good solution. You are relying on an implementation detail of the standard library implementation that could change at any moment without warning. I will add a proper example later. Unfortunately it isn't quite as straight-forward.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's sketchy.  I look forward to a better example when you have time.  For now, I'm going to create my own type using the same technique as the stl is doing.  I'm still working on understanding some of these concepts.

Comment: @LeoViolette See my edit.