# Passing variadic template parameter to another function with a variadic template parameter

Tags: c++, string, stl, format, c++20

I'm currently writing a logger for my engine and I've been stuck with a problem I could not solve. [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) takes in a constant string and a list of arguments after.

My Log functions is as follows:

```
template <typename... Args>
void Log(const char* message, Args&&... args)
```

Now in somewhere in the function scope, I try to format the string by:

```
std::string formattedMsg = std::format(message, args);
```

And I try to mess with it:

```
Scope<Colour::Logger> myLogger = CreateScope<Colour::Logger>("MyLogger");
myLogger->Log("Hey! I have a variable named \"a\" and it is equal to {0}", a);
myLogger->Info("Hey! I have a variable named \"a\" and it is equal to {0}", a);
myLogger->Log("Hey! I have a variable named \"a\" and it is equal to {0}", a);
myLogger->Warn("Hey! I have a variable named \"a\" and it is equal to {0}", a);
myLogger->Error("Hey! I have a variable named \"a\" and it is equal to {0}", a);
myLogger->Fatal("Hey! I have a variable named \"a\" and it is equal to {0}", a);
myLogger->Info("Hey! I have a variable named \"a\" and it is equal to {0}", a);
```

> Scope is unique_ptr, CreateScope is make_unique. Info, Fatal, Trace etc. functions just set the level to correct one and call Log().

But that gives me the error:

> std::_Basic_format_string::_Basic_format_string': call to immediate function is not a constant expression

I tried doing stuff like taking in a _Fmt_String, std::string, const char*, I tried expanding the arguments, forwarding them but none of them work. How can I format this `message` parameter using the `args` parameter using `std::format`?

Comment: _"As of [P2216R3](https://wg21.link/P2216R3), it is an error if the format string is not a constant expression. [`std::vformat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/vformat) can be used in this case."_

Comment: Doesn't work as well (and it takes in a std::wstring, I need std::string).

Comment: I saw a very similar question a couple of days ago.

Comment: @HycroftMolmes `std::vformat` has overloads to take `std::string` too. What error do you get when using `std::vformat`?

Comment: Dup? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72323185/6752050

Comment: Related to [how-to-create-a-function-that-forwards-its-arguments-to-fmtformat-keeping-the-type-safeness?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68675303/how-to-create-a-function-that-forwards-its-arguments-to-fmtformat-keeping-the)

Comment: Dup? [Wrapping std::format in a template function fails to compile with the latest MSVC compiler update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72243483/wrapping-stdformat-in-a-template-function-fails-to-compile-with-the-latest-msv)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might get you started :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <format>

template <typename... args_t>
void Log(std::string_view fmt, args_t&&... args)
{
    std::string formatted_message = std::vformat(fmt, std::make_format_args(args...));
    std::cout << formatted_message << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    Log("Hello {0}{1}", "World", "!");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know I had to use `make_format_args`.

Comment: Arguments to make_format_args shouldn't be forwarded, see e.g. http://eel.is/c++draft/format#functions-2

Comment: @vitaut the std::forward has become a bit of an automatism with me when using &&. So thank you for this fix.